# @Autowired in Applicationcontext filter class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, autowired

@Autowired annotation returns the error when accessing from the applicationcontext custom filter class.

inside application context

```
<sec:custom-filter ref="userFilter"position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />        <beans:bean id="userFilter" class="com.xxx.xxx.web.xxx.UserFilter">
```

UserFilter class accesing the service from database.

```
 @Autowired @Qualifier("userService")
 private UserService userService;
```

In service class I am using as given below.

```
Service(value="userService")
Component("userService")    
public class UserService.
```

Insteaded of autowire annotation method I followed the below method working fine.

```
UserService userService= new UserService();
```

I am getting the error when using the autowire annotation in the applicationcontext filter class.
I can able to use Autowire annotation in all other class's which is available in the application.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Mar 06 17:41:56 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:346) [spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:333) [spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880) [spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:841) [spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4980) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5626) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_67]
2015-03-06 17:41:57,425 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1] - [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext]- Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Mar 06 17:41:56 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:359) [spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:888) [spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:841) [spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4980) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5626) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_67]
Mar 06, 2015 5:41:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:170)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:921)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:841)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4980)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5626)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please find the below application context

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

```
<!-- Import service layer -->
<beans:import resource="classpath:serviceDEVContext.xml" />

<!-- <beans:bean id="authService"
    class="com.bosch.bdxdb.web.userservice.AuthServiceImpl" /> -->

<!-- windows authentication provider -->
<beans:bean id="waffleWindowsAuthProvider"
    class="waffle.windows.auth.impl.WindowsAuthProviderImpl" />

<!-- collection of security filters -->
<beans:bean id="negotiateSecurityFilterProvider"
    class="waffle.servlet.spi.NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="waffleWindowsAuthProvider" />
    <beans:property name="protocols">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>Negotiate</beans:value>
            <beans:value>NTLM</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="basicSecurityFilterProvider"
    class="waffle.servlet.spi.BasicSecurityFilterProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="waffleWindowsAuthProvider" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="waffleSecurityFilterProviderCollection"
    class="waffle.servlet.spi.SecurityFilterProviderCollection">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="negotiateSecurityFilterProvider" />
            <beans:ref bean="basicSecurityFilterProvider" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<sec:global-method-security
    secured-annotations="enabled" />

<sec:http security="none" pattern="/favicon.ico" />


<!-- spring filter entry point -->
<sec:http entry-point-ref="negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="userFilter"
        position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
</sec:http>
<beans:bean id="negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint"
    class="waffle.spring.NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="Provider"
        ref="waffleSecurityFilterProviderCollection" />
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="waffleSpringAuthenticationProvider" class="waffle.spring.WindowsAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="AuthProvider" ref="waffleWindowsAuthProvider" />
</beans:bean>
<!-- spring authentication provider -->
<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationProvider"/>
<!-- <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationProvider">
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="waffleSpringAuthenticationProvider" />
</sec:authentication-manager> -->
<!-- <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"> <sec:authentication-provider 
    user-service-ref="authService"></sec:authentication-provider> </sec:authentication-manager> -->

<!-- spring security filter -->
<beans:bean id="waffleNegotiateSecurityFilter" class="com.xxx.xxx.web.waffle.userFilter">
    <beans:property name="Provider"
        ref="waffleSecurityFilterProviderCollection" />
    <beans:property name="AllowGuestLogin" value="false" />
    <beans:property name="PrincipalFormat" value="fqn" />
```

</beans:property> -->

Comment: Could you please share the complete application context xml?

Comment: Sorry I can not able to share my applicationcontext file.

Comment: Please add the configuration xml in the question itself. It is much easier to read.

Comment: Make sure you scan the UserService component in applicationContext.xml  using  <context:component-scan base-package="xx.xx."/>  up to the package name of UserService.

Comment: <context:component-scan base-package="xx.xx."/> I have added in the serviceDevcontext file, one more thing is autowire annotation working fine with other classes.only problem is when i am using the application filter class.My doubt is it possible to use the annotation in the applicationcontext file filter class itself.I am using this when applicationcontext control goes out in the applicationcontext file.